# Allow ec2:TerminateInstance only on self?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have a worker machine running on a spot instance with a dedicated role. I'd like to grant it the permission to run ec2-terminate-instances when it finishes but want it to be able to terminate only itself.

Couldn't find any variable of instance-id or something similar. How do I define that kind of permission?

I've also tried using `shutdown -h now` but the behaviour with spot instances was a bit weird - it killed the machine (terminated) but kept the spot request as `fulfilled` (rather than `terminated-by-user`)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the behavior you described actually wrong?  The spot request *was* fulfilled.  Within a few minutes, the spot service will realize that the instance halted itself and the spot request will show the expected status.   *Note that even if you terminate a Spot Instance before you cancel its request, there might be a delay before the Spot service detects that your Spot Instance was terminated. In this case, the request state can either be closed or canceled.* http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-bid-status.html#spot-instances-bid-status-lifecycle

Comment: Agree. It took a minute or two until the spot request updated as well. That gap is a different challenge but a manageable one.

Comment: It's not clear that `ec2-terminate-instances` would necessarily even produce a different result than the instance halting itself from the inside, and the time lag for the spot service to detect the halted instance should not result in billable time -- the spot instance isn't running at that point, and the spot request status seems "informational" rather than "authoritative."